# May I play a computer game which includes Greek mythological creatures?

Tags: halacha, technology, avodah-zarah, games-toys

I sometimes play a computer role-playing game (RPG) in which my character fights creatures and retrieves treasure.

But some of the creatures are derived from Greek mythology. Is it still permissible for me to play the game?

[CYLOR](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146/why-is-it-necessary-to-ask-a-rabbi).

<sub>Related: [While playing a computer game, may I “worship” one of the game's “gods” to help me win?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28057/while-playing-a-computer-game-may-i-worship-one-of-the-games-gods-to-help)</sub>

Comment: Note: Like Wikipedia, this site makes no guarantee of validity, and does not offer professional (particularly rabbinic) advice. Treat information from this site like it came from a crowd of your friends.

Comment: Not sure that I understand the question. You mean things like griffins, phoenixes, hydras and basilisks, etc? If so, nobody ever worshipped such things. What's the problem?

Comment: @ShimonbM: Excellent comment. Yes, those kinds of creatures. 1. I don't know much about Greek mythology; I'm not sure I knew that nobody worshipped them until I saw your comment. 2. Or maybe, since the mythology includes idolatrous ideas, I worried that perhaps even the non-idolatrous parts were forbidden.

Comment: @ShimonbM You realize that two of those came from us, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked my local Orthodox rabbi: the (Chareidi) morah d'asrah of a mid-sized Orthodox shul in a North American city of about three million people. He prefers that I not specify his name here.

He told me that, even if a game includes Greek mythological creatures, it's not a concern nowadays.

Comment: Can you get his reasoning and [edit] it in, by any chance?

Comment: @msh210: Unfortunately I have too many other things on my mind. :(

Comment: The Greek pantheon, and many others, are considered as real nowadays as snow white or Cinderella. Since the have fallen into the category of fairy tales basically, I have heard that they are for all intents and purposes not gods, for example, sayIng Zeus is not a violation of saying the names of other gods, because is effectively not a god anymore.