# May one listen to Mozart's The Magic Flute?

Tags: avodah-zarah, music, performance-entertainment

[The Magic Flute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Magic_Flute) is a famous opera by Mozart. Its lyrics can be found [here](http://www.aria-database.com/translations/magic_flute.txt).

It seems to be completely secular to me. It includes lyrics that include characters talking to pagan gods, but Mozart himself did not believe in these gods; it is part of a characterization.

```
O Isis und Osiris,  schenket            O Isis and Osiris, give 
der Weisheit Geist dem neuen Paar!      The spirit of wisdom to the new pair!
```

Comment: perhaps related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29094

Comment: Reminds me that there used to be Jewish books printed with re-used gate pages that featured Greek and Roman gods. Sometimes they tried to hide this by writing David and Shlomo above them, or something like that.