# Is there a problem 'wearing' a virtual Saint Lucia hat?

Tags: internet, christianity, non-jewish-holidays, stackexchange, hukot-hagoyim

Is there any prohibition, perhaps related to lo teileichu b'hukat hagoyim, in "wearing" a virtual hat which [celebrates Saint Lucia day](http://rbth.com/photo_of_the_day/2014/12/14/celebrating_st_lucias_day_42237.html)?

[image: Saint Lucia hat from WinterBash 2014 on Mi Yodeya; the hat is made of nine candles and a wreath]

---

[Related](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3316/why-is-there-a-saint-lucia-hat-on-mi-yodeya)

Comment: I'm just interpreting it as a chanukiah with really weird perspective, so as to avoid that. Anyway, it's virtual!

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt does virtual make it ok? Can a person use an image of an idol for their avatar since it is virtual?

Comment: Is the intention of the user to promote avodah zarah? Anyway, I don't see how we're benefiting from it, hence the virtual comment.

Comment: @user6641 But I engage in virtual avoda zara all the time in video games! Are you saying that I can only play Antimage in Dota?

Comment: @rosenjcb [asked](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28057/while-playing-a-computer-game-may-i-worship-one-of-the-games-gods-to-help) and answered

Comment: @user6641 That's the last time I pick up quest items for a troll shaman again.

Comment: @user6641, the comments and source seem to imply that the rav who paskened that answer did not actually understand the concept of gaming.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt agreed, I didn't say answered "correctly" ;)

Comment: @user6641, apologies, I misread your phrasing.

Comment: When I Googled Saint Lucia, all the items on the first page referred to an island in the Caribbean.  While I have no doubt there was a person called Saint Lucia at some point, I just counted the candles and thought it would be nice for Hannuakah.  Call me naive if you like...

Comment: @Mike, I tried recreating your experiment, but adding the word "day" afterwards. [This was my first result](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St_Lucy's_Day).

Comment: @Yishai Yasher koach!  You obviously have superior Google-fu.

Answer (score 2):

The [first mishnah in Avodah Zoro says](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Avodah_Zarah.1/en/Open_Mishna),

> 1 During the three days preceding the festivals of the non-Jews, it is
>   forbidden to do business with them, to lend them something or to
>   borrow something from them, to lend [money] to them or to borrow
>   [money] from them, to resolve your debt to them or to have them
>   resolve their debt to you. Rabbi Yehuda says: One can have them
>   resolve their debt since it causes him distress. They [the Sages] said
>   to him: even though he might be in distress at the outset, eventually
>   he will be joyful.

Bartenura points out that we are worried lest the idolator goes to his place of worship on his festival and feels good about his idol and thanks it for the successful deal.

This suggests that it is not allowed to give opportunities for the idolators to feel good about their idols. I suggest that Chazal did not want to forbid all business contacts with the idolators and so limited the prohibition to three days preceding the festivals.

Now if (1) the origin of this hat is avodoh zoro and (2) by wearing this hat one would be giving any support or encouragement to its adherents ("see our idol is so wonderful even the Jews wear virtual hats devoted to it"), then I suggest that it would be forbidden or at least not encouraged to wear the said hat.

But I doubt whether both conditions (1) and (2) are fulfilled these days.