# Real money trading in online games

Tags: halacha, internet, money, business, games-toys

1. Is farming virtual currencies(like world of warcraft gold) in online games and then selling it for real money allowed?
2. Is it considered like stealing from the company that owns the game?
3. Is boosting players for real money in games like league of legends allowed?
4. Is selling game accounts for real money allowed?

   It is stated in most TOS that it is forbidden to sell currency and accounts.

   Also in some TOS it is stated that the company owns everything in the game.

   Boosting is also not allowed.

   Farming currency means acquiring it by doing certain actions in the game like killing monsters and then you give it to someone else in the game and he gives you real money outside of the game.

   Boosting means someone pays you real money outside of the game for you to play from his account and increase his rank.

   Also in some games the company sells the currency for real money inside the game but its much more expensive and when you sell the currency outside without the approval of the company you place a lower price and thus causing players to dont buy from the company.

   But it is you who makes the gold and the account by playing.

Comment: mkroa, [welcome to Mi Yodeya](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887), and thanks for bringing this interesting set of questions here! Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting.

Comment: Could you please [edit] this post to clarify: A) what you mean by "farming" and "boosting" (so people who are expert in Judaism but not MMORPG can contribute), and B) why you think that these actions may count as stealing or may otherwise be prohibited by Judaism?

Comment: It seems like all the questions here can be boiled down to "Can one do something against the cmpany's terms of service in a video game?".

Comment: @Salmononius2 I see nothing in the question that indicates that such actions violate TOS.

Comment: @msh210 True, I was likely reading in to the question using my own knowledge of video games and my own understanding of the question. Otherwise, I don't really see any reason why all those things wouldn't be allowed. Why wouldn't you be allowed to sell your goods and services for money? But that's really up to the questioner to clarify.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the process. But, offhand, this sounds similar to trading in casino chips. The chips aren't worth anything until you exchange them for cash. I sometimes play online Scrabble, and I collect "points" which I can exchange for prizes or cash, etc. That's part of the game rules. What's wrong with that and how is that different than what you described?

Comment: @mkroa Please see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts regarding how to merge the unregistered previous account into the new registered one. Then, you'll be able to [edit] your post. When you do, please try to make the post work as a well-written whole. For an example of a post that explains its background and concerns well while presenting its question, see https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28057/while-playing-a-computer-game-may-i-worship-one-of-the-games-gods-to-help

Comment: mkroa, glad to see you succeeded in uniting your accounts. Could you please edit this post to be a united whole? No need to differentiate between original text and later additions; we're making a permanent Q&A artifact, so it's important for it to be readble and compelling, not a history of revisions (which we have [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/91265/revisions) for).